# Scroll uiviewscrollview without calling viewDidscroll

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

The current Problem is lack of control over the scroll view when the user flick scrolls...What i am currently trying to achieve is when the user flick scrolls is that when the scroll speed goes below a certain threshold i set the contentoffset...preferably by animation, problem is it then calls viewdDidScroll after i call to setContentOffset animated. Which than calls all my code again, and it causes the scrollView to go a bit jittery. there also does not seem to be a way to cause the scrollview to stop instantly.

so in bullet points i need

-To stop the UI scroll view on command.

-To not call viewDidScroll when setting the content offset via animation

Does anyone have a clue to overcome any of this

Comment: 1. To stop the `UIScrollView`, just set its `contentOffset` to a new value without animating, it should stop any running animation. 2. Create an `BOOL animating` variable, that you set to `YES` when you start the animation, and to `NO` when the animation ends (via the delegate). Then in `scrollViewDidScroll:` check the value of your `animating` variable. (Also note, if this is any help, that `contentOffset` is animatable in a `UIView` animation block, even if you don't use `setContentOffset:animated:`).